# while validating duplicate records I am getting error

Tags: r

with the below data frame I am finding duplicates records, but data frame also have NA's and "" cells. i also want to ignore Na's and blank cells. (without changing original data base)

1. checking duplicates in name part of email
2. checking duplicates in all columns

do we have any other better and simple solution for this...??

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092","BBB7203"),
                 name = c("adam,link","tt,dy","adam,link","gbesada","dojeda","    slew"," alpucheta","    rzona","jachaval","allo,nuny","mbautis","rgrandinettizzy","jali","kintom","namoti,mew","rohan,sah",NA,NA,NA,NA,"",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","sah.rohan@abcd.com","","","",NA,"",""))


Employee_ID = "EMP.ID"
Name  = "name"
Email = "email"



df <- df %>% mutate(Name = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)')) %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(`11. duplicates before @` = case_when(n() >1 & !is.na(Name) ~ "11. Email has duplicate name before @", TRUE ~ ''))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Employee_ID, Email,Name), ~as.integer(duplicated(.,incomparables = c("", NA))), .names = '{c(1,3,54)} unique {c(col)}'))


``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a crack at your problem. With the code below you can identify duplicated values in your columns in interest as well as in the name part of emails while ignore NA and blank values. I rely on the [`duplicated`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/duplicated) function that identifies duplicates and allows you to ignore certain values.

```
# Create the dataset
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092","BBB7203"),
                 name = c("adam,link","tt,dy","adam,link","gbesada","dojeda","    slew"," alpucheta","    rzona","jachaval","allo,nuny","mbautis","rgrandinettizzy","jali","kintom","namoti,mew","rohan,sah",NA,NA,NA,NA,"",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","sah.rohan@abcd.com","","","",NA,"",""),
                 "duplicated before @"="",
                 "1 unique Employee ID"="",
                 "3 Unique email"="",
                 "4 Unique Name"="",
                 check.names=FALSE)

# Trim white space
df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, MARGIN=2, 
                          FUN=function(values){
                                 gsub(pattern=" ", replacement="", values)
                              }))

# Note values to ignore
valuesToIgnore <- c("", NA)

# Identify duplicated names in emails
indicesOfAtSymbol <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern='@', df$email))
namesFromEmails <- substr(df$email, 1, indicesOfAtSymbol-1)
df$`duplicated before @`[duplicated(namesFromEmails, incomparables=valuesToIgnore)] <- "11. Email has duplicate name before @"

# Identify duplicated names
df$`4 Unique Name`[duplicated(df$name, incomparables=valuesToIgnore)] <- 1

# Identify duplicated IDs
df$`1 unique Employee ID`[duplicated(df$EMP.ID, incomparables=valuesToIgnore)] <- 1

# Identify duplicated emails
df$`3 Unique email`[duplicated(df$email, incomparables=valuesToIgnore)] <- 1
```

The above results in the following table:
[image]

Which I note isn't quite what you are looking for but hopefully it gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092","BBB7203"),
                 name = c("adam,link","tt,dy","adam,link","gbesada","dojeda","    slew"," alpucheta","    rzona","jachaval","allo,nuny","mbautis","rgrandinettizzy","jali","kintom","namoti,mew","rohan,sah",NA,NA,NA,NA,"",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","sah.rohan@abcd.com","","","",NA,"",""))

library(data.table)
# Convert to data.table
df <- data.table(df)
# Get column names
my_cols <- names(df)
# Delete blank spaces in all columns
df[, (my_cols) := lapply(.SD, trimws), .SDcols = my_cols]
# Set NA's to blanc
df[df == ""] <- NA
# Duplicated in email name part
df[!is.na(name), email_name_duplicated := .N > 1, str_extract(email, '.*(?=@)')]
# Duplicated cols names
dupli_cols <-  paste0("dupli_", my_cols)
# Get the duplicated cols
df[, (dupli_cols) := lapply(.SD, duplicated, incomparables = NA), .SDcols = my_cols]
```